# Intellij: navigate to custom declaration based upon string in Java file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the following Java snippet -

```
load("directory/filename.ext");
```

How can I configure IntelliJ so I can navigate to that file using the Navigate > Declaration option (Command/Ctrl + B) when my caret is on the text `directory/filename.ext`.  If I need a specific plugin, can you please share the name of the plugin and how to configure it?

My workaround at the moment is to highlight the text and navigate to the file.  But, I'm looking for a solution using the declaration option.

Answer (score 1):

V13 or later support "injecting references". Enable plugin "IntelliLang" (bundled), place cursor on the expression, invoke Alt+Enter and select "Inject Language/Reference", choose "File Reference" from the popup

Comment: Thanks, I have 12, but let me see how I can get an upgrade to 13 and then I'll verify.